# Using JQuery To Change Color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a game I have been working on here, that will change a `td` you click on to a color dependent on a variable. I want this variable to be randomly chosen between two strings, either 'lime' or 'red' I have that part down. The problem is applying the CSS to the `td`'s, as far as I can tell, I am doing it correctly, but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
$().ready(function(){
  //Functions
  $('td').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('block')) return;
    $(this).addClass(color);
    $(this).addClass('block');
    $(this).css('background-color:'+color);
    tilesLeft--;
    if(color=='lime'){color='red';}else{color='lime';}
  });
  
  //Variables
  var color;
  var tilesLeft = 9;
  
  //Setup
  if(Math.round(Math.random())==0){color='lime';}else{color='red';}
});

//Intervals
setInterval(function(){
  $('header').css('color:'+color);
},1);
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin:1px;
  width:30%;height:30%;
}

#board {height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Tic Tac Toe</header>
<table style='width:100%;height:95%;'>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

The two things that are wrong with this are:

- The `$(this).css('background-color:'+color);` is not changing the background color
- The `$(this).css('color:'+color);` is not changing the text color

Thanks for the help!

Comment: remove the colon, replace the plus with a comma(,).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right:

```
$(this).css('background-color', color);
```

The above, perhaps obviously, assumes that the the `color` variable is successfully set to a valid CSS color-string.

It seems you were trying to pass a string, perhaps to the `style` attribute; instead the `css()` method offers two approaches, a `'property','value'`:

```
css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or an object of property-values:

```
css({
    'background-color' : 'red'
});
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Basic Color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#html4).
  - [Extended Color keywords](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: String-concatenation does, yes; but you don't need to concatenate the strings. Is the `color` variable set? What is it set *to*?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, change

```
$(this).css('background-color:'+color);
```

to

```
$(this).css({
  backgroundColor: color
});
```

and

```
$('header').css('color:'+color);
```

to

```
 $('header').css({
    color: color
 });
```

Put your interval inside the ready state :)

And it will work :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Functions
  $('td').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('block')) return;
    $(this).addClass(color);
    $(this).addClass('block');
    $(this).css({
      backgroundColor: color
    });
    tilesLeft--;
    if (color == 'lime') {
      color = 'red';
    } else {
      color = 'lime';
    }
  });

  //Variables
  var color;
  var tilesLeft = 9;

  //Setup
  if (Math.round(Math.random()) == 0) {
    color = 'lime';
  } else {
    color = 'red';
  }

  //Intervals
  setInterval(function() {
    $('header').css({
      color: color
    });
  }, 1);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
}
#board {
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Tic Tac Toe</header>
<table style='width:100%;height:95%;'>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```